# DC voltmeter gives unknown reading when powered

Tags: troubleshooting, voltmeter

I just bought a *DC 3 wired voltmeter* and it was working perfectly. Here is it image:

[image]

I used the yellow wire for measuring the voltages. But for some reason, I desoldered the wires and soldered pin headers. Now it gives unknown reading like 0.XY (eg 0.37) whenever I just connect the positive and negative to battery. It was not happening before.
Can I be helped to troubleshoot what I did wrong? Have I damage the circuit?

Here is the underneath image of the one I soldered:

[image]

Comment: those pins do not appear to be soldered to the PCB

Comment: Is the battery voltage too low by any chance?

Comment: @winny I am providing it 5V.

Comment: Strange. It’s however my go to thing with incorrect readings on DMM (yours is similar but not a DMM) as low battery voltage often give high readings.

Comment: What are you connecting the 'pin headers' to?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am connecting the pin headers to breadboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason I can think of why you'd get different behavior if you did the desolder/solder job well.

The underneath part you show doesn't show good solder flow around the added header pins. So perhaps there's an intermittent problem due to poor/lack-of soldering?

But otherwise, I don't know of a reason why replacing wires with header pins should change its behavior.